# Hive error when declaring hivevar

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

Trying to declare a variable in Hive using Hue online. Using the following code:

```
SET hivevar:TABLE1=location.tablename;
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:12 missing KW_ROLE at 'hivevar' near 'hivevar' line 1:19 missing EOF at ':' near 'hivevar'.
```

Can anyone tell me what this error message means or even what the KW_ROLE statement means?

Answer (score 4):

Do you by any chance have a comment above that instruction ? Are you running that line and that line only ?

For example, the following will raise a similar Exception :

```
--This is a comment
SET hivevar:TABLE1=location.tablename;
```

But it works fine without the comment.

Comment: Yes I just tried it again removing all whitespace and literally only having the line:

Comment: It happened to me too. Do you know why we can't put comment as the first line?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are making changes in MAC/Windows and moving the script to the server, Double dash "--" in MAC is a different from double dash "--" on Linux server, make changes on server itself and run the script...